# modelling an ER diagram for django

Tags: django, composite-primary-key

I needed some help to convert to tables and later to django's models, using Django's Admin interface, two entities (Item, Prototype) where:

- Item can be a standalone object or be part of one prototype **only**
- Prototype exists only if it contains at least an Item
- A Prototype can contain many **different** items.

The ER diagram should be this:
[image]

At the Django side I wished: from the PrototypeAdmin to include any Item(s) and from ItemAdmin to assign  to one prototype like in the followings pictures:
[image: addChangeItem] [image: addChangePrototype]

I made some attempts designing different models but I'm not fully satisfied of my results (one try implies many NULLs, another gives an admin interface not very easy to use, from another one I can only add Items to protype..)

**EDIT:**
 
My first attempt was to design a Prototype table with two primary keys, but I discovered Django doesn't work well with them and also I don't have any widget inside ItemAdmin to assign the Item to a prototype:

```
    Items: (ItemID, itemName)
    Prototypes:(PrototypeID,ItemID,prototypeName)
```

Another attempt gives out a table of Items with 95% of NULL FKs (we have only few prototypes!)  and also I needed to guarantee uniqueness of  prototypeID--ItemID, but it's good for the GUI I wanted (the two previous pictures):

```
   Items: (ItemID, itemName, prototype(FK))
   Prototypes:(PrototypeID,prototypeName)
```

another attempt which solves the problem of thousands of NULLs, but at the Django's side while I can add many items to a prototype with a TabularInline, I don't like to use another TabularInline for selecting which prototype to assign to an item (I wished a dropdown instead):

```
    Items: (ItemID, itemName, prototype(FK))
    Prototypes:(PrototypeID,prototypeName)
    linkTableProtoItems: (lnk_ID, prototype(FK), item(FK))
```

Comment: Please post your attempted design, and for each explain _clearly_ why it doesn't fit. Also, the schema design shouldn't be didacted by the default admin features (you can write your own admin views to have something that matches your need instead).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers   I've done it. Thanks for any help. The fact is that I'm not a programmer since long time and now there are too many things to learn that one life can't be enough.. so at the moment I'm choosing the easiest way of the django Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your specs, ie:

> Item can be a standalone object or be part of one prototype only
>   Prototype exists only if it contains at least an Item
>   A Prototype can contain many different items.

The nearest schema is your second one:

> Items: (ItemID, itemName, prototype(FK))
>
> Prototypes:(PrototypeID,prototypeName)

The other ones are not valid: the first one doesn't respect "A Prototype can contain many different items" and the third one doesn't respect "Item can be part of one prototype only".

The fact that 95% or more of `item.prototype_id` are null it not an issue in any way.

Comment: Ok, I will go for the second one then, but I'm open to modified the diagram. Do you think it can be enhanced somehow? Maybe using two different primary keys for the Prototype entity?

Comment: "Do you think it can be enhanced somehow?" => no, why ? That's the schema that matches your rules, period. Relational database modeling is not arbitrary, (not totally at least) it's based on well-known rules. You are of course free to not follow those rules but at the cost of uselessly complex code, stale, incoherent, or just plain totally corrupted and unfixable data,  maintainance nightmare etc.

Comment: "Maybe using two different primary keys for the Prototype entity" => The definition of a _primary_ key is that it's THE "primary" key. You can have as many unique (or unique together) constraints as you want (well, as it makes sense - here again this is not arbitrary) but you only have one single PK. What would you do with another one anyway ?

Comment: I'm sorry, too many days I'm struggling with this problem and my brain fried. I had to write "composite key", e.g.  "prototypeID" and "itemID", so the third case could be linkPrototypeItem: lnkID(PK), prototypeID(CK),itemID(CK)

Comment: This would be for a many to many relationship, IOW an item could be part of many prototypes - which violates ""Item can be part of one prototype only". Once again, those aren't arbitrary decisions, your business rules dictate the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Items: (ItemID, itemName)

Prototypes:(PrototypeID,ItemID,prototypeName)

in Items relation, ItemID must be the primary key and in Protorypes relation, PrototypeID must be the primary key. But ItemID in Prototypes relation will be a foreign key which references to Items relation.